# How do I show who created/owns a file in the Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

I wish to see who created a file or who has ownership of a file within the list view of Finder.

Specifically I'm looking at a network Samba volume and can see the owner and group within Terminal.

*UPDATE*: Using the finder to show the permissions is not enough as it does not tell me who the owner is. Notice below two users have the "Read & Write" permission.

[image: Multiple read & write for a file in finder]

Inspecting the file with terminal shows that the file is owned by 'rpopp'.

[image: File owner shown in terminal]

Also note that I wish to show this property in finders list view for all files at once.

[image]

Comment: Try Command+I while highlighting a file.  Do you need more information than what is shown there?

Comment: Yeah, the creator/owner does not appear in the info window, I also wish to see this as a column to see all files at once rather than a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate this doesn't completely answer your question as its not a modification to Finder, but I've previously used [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) to do this - assuming you're willing to pay for and use a 3rd party application (though its does have a 30-day trial).

[image]

Comment: binarybob, this could be the ticket for me, though it does sound overkill to buy a separate tool to just get the one field I'm after displaying. I'll have a think about it though and see. Are you aware if you can use the same tool on multiple computers? I've noticed it's not available in the app-store.

Comment: @BrettRyan Looks like it according to... [Can I install one Path Finder license onto multiple Macs?](http://support.cocoatech.com/kb/purchase-registration/can-i-install-one-path-finder-license-onto-multiple-macs)

Comment: Excellent, thanks binarybob, I haven't yet purchased this software though it looks the ticket so I will mark your answer as accepted. Thankyou for your help.